# Understanding Spectrogram parameters

Tags: matlab, parameters, spectrogram

I came across this coding while learning:

`[S,F,T,y] = spectrogram(samples, WINDOW, NOVERLAP, nfft, fs)`;

What exactly is being assigned to `S`,`F`,`T` and `y`?

Answer (score 0):

If you read Matlab's `spectrogram` carefully, it has all the information you need on there. According to [Matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html#outputarg_ps)

The 4 parameters are:

S - The full complex Short-Time Fourier Transform a.k.a your spectrogram.

F - The cyclical frequencies returned as a vector.

T - The time instants/or temporal frames returned as a vector.

and finally y - the 4th output (regularly written as ps) is the Power Spectrum Density (PSD) in the form of a matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused about parameter 'y'

Comment: So I run the above code and checks for `size(y)` and it says `ans = 257 841` and I came across this `nfreq = size(y,1);`. What does this mean?

Comment: I cannot possibly know what all your notations are, the size of (y) seems to suggest that you have 257 frequency bins across 841 time frames, so `nfreq` I expect means the number of Frequency bins or you can think of it as the frequency resolution. BUT again, I have no way of knowing for certain.

Comment: Yes, after reading on the Internet, I believe `nfreq` is the frequency resolution too. Do you perhaps know how to calculate mel filter by making use of `nfreq`? I've been trying to do this for days but nothing appeared on my graph.

Comment: What do you mean by calculate mel filter? the Mel Filter bank you are referring to (i.e. in MFCC?) The Mel filter bank is implemented in many toolboxes, i.e.http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23179-melfilter/content/melfilter.m If you read the input, the Frequency Vector is your nfreq

Comment: Oh, so the `melfilter()` can compute the filterbank automatically? I didn't know that. If you could refer to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/274169-why-my-mel-filters-do-not-overlap-on-each-other), basically I want to plot my 26 mel filterbanks but they don't overlap on each other as they should be.

Comment: I need clarification on one thing: If I'm using `spectrogram()`, I do not need to compute the DFT and PSD anymore? 'Cause I think my confusion arise from this. All of the basic tutorials on MFCC told me to calculate the DFT, magnitude spectrum then compute Mel freq filter bank.

Comment: the `sepctrogram` toolbox does the DFT for you using specified parameters in the call of the function.